# How to hide or show a column after a jquery data table AJAX callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, datatables, paging

Using JQuery data tables it is easy to retrieve the content of the table using AJAX .  The problem I am having us the ability to hide or show a column as the user pages through the data. In the table there is a column with a check box but not all the rows will have the checkbox. If the current page does not have any rows with checkboxes how do I hid that column and them have it be shown when to user pages (using the data table paging functionality) to a page with rows containing text boxes?

Comment: It seems like using a callback like [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback) might be the place to call such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer:

In `fnDrawCallback`, call `this.fnSetColumnVis( 5, true);` to show the 6th column (0 is the first column) and `this.fnSetColumnVis( 5, false);` to hide that same column.

Comment: In the actual version of datatables not working. This create a bucle and the web crash :(

Comment: The version fail is 1.10 to 1.10.2

Answer (score 2):

Example:-

```
oTable = $('#call_list_table').dataTable({
............//do stuff here
});
oTable.fnSetColumnVis(1, false);//hide second column
oTable.fnSetColumnVis(1, true);//show second column

//Note: column start form 0(zero) index
```